# Get rows with the maximum date from a query

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, having-clause

How to get all rows with the maximum date from a query in PostgreSQL?

For example, if I got the following rows:

```
1, 1, '2014-05-27'
2, 2, '2014-05-26'
3, 3, '2014-05-26'
4, 4, '2014-05-25'
5, 5, '2014-05-27'
```

I need to get this result:

```
1, 1, '2014-05-27'
5, 5, '2014-05-27'
```

Only the ones with the maximum date - but *all* of those.
This gets it done by *repeating* the query in a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE field_1 = '1'
AND date_1 = (SELECT MAX(date_1) FROM table WHERE field_1 = '1');
```

Is there a simpler / faster way (without repeating the query)?
Maybe with the `HAVING` clause?

Comment: HAVING doesn't apply here. It is used to filter results based on the value of an aggregate, but your result set includes no aggregate.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work:

```
select *
from table table1 join (
    select max(date_1) theMaxDate from table) table2
on table1. date_1= table2. theMaxDate
```

Here we are selecting the MaxDate from the table (aliased as table2).  This maxDate will be referenced as table2.theMaxDate.

Then we join with the the table (which I referenced as table1 but that's not required).

We join where the date in table1 equals the max date from table2.

I don't think you can do this with a having.

Does this work for you?

Answer (score 0):

This might work ;)

```
SELECT *
  FROM table
  WHERE field_1 = '1'
  ORDER BY date_1 DESC
  LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0
```

Comment: There is no need to specify `OFFSET` with every `LIMIT`.

Comment: I need all records but not only the first one

Answer (score 0):

To get *only rows for the latest date in the query* use the window function [**`rank()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html).
You *need* a subquery (or CTE), because window functions are applied after `WHERE` and `HAVING`.

The `HAVING` clause is not applicable without because you are not aggregating rows.

```
SELECT *
FROM  (
    SELECT *, rank() OVER (ORDER BY date_1 DESC) AS rnk
    FROM   tbl
    WHERE  field_1 = '1'
    ) sub
WHERE  rnk = 1;
```

Your original query may be even faster for simple cases. Indexes on `field_1` and `date_1` are the key to good performance. The optimum for either query would be a [multicolumn index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-multicolumn.html):

```
CREATE INDEX foo ON tbl (field_1, date_1 DESC);
```

If date_1 can be NULL you may want to use NULLS LAST in index *and* query. See:

- [PostgreSQL sort by datetime asc, null first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/postgresql-sort-by-datetime-asc-null-first/9511492#9511492)